# How to return dynamically created vectors to the workspace?

Tags: excel, matlab, eval

Hello I'm trying to write a function which reads a certain type of spreadsheet and creates vectors dynamically from it's data then returns said vectors to the workspace.

My xlcs is structured by rows, in the first row there is a string which should become the name of the vector and the rest of the rows contain the numbers which make up the vector.

Here is my code:

```
function [ B ] = read_excel(filename)
%read_excel a function to read time series data from spreadsheet

% I get the contents of the first cell to know what to name the vector
[nr, name]=xlsread(filename, 'sheet1','A2:A2');

% Transform it to a string
name_str = char(name);

% Create a filename from it
varname=genvarname(name_str);

% Get the numbers which will make up the vector
A=xlsread(filename,'B2:CT2');

% Create the vector with the corect name and data
eval([varname '= A;']);

end
```

As far as I can tell the vector is created corectly, but I have no ideea how to return it to the workspace.

Preferably the solution should be able to return a indeterminate nr of vectors as this is just a prototype and I want the function to return a nr of vectors of the user's choice at once.

To be more precise, the vector varname is created I can use it in the script, if I add:

```
eval(['plot(',varname,')'])
```

it will plot the vector, but for my purposes I need the vector varname to be returned to the workspace to persist after the script is run.

Comment: What is the difference between the vector getting "created correctly" and getting "returned to the workspace"? They sound like the same thing to me

Comment: No vector shows up in my workspace after I run the script, I'm assuming the vector is created but it remains local only the script can use it.

Comment: That's because its a function, not a script. I suggest you put them all in a struct and return that. I'll post an answer with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is a function, you need to pass the variables you create to an output variable. I suggest you do it through a struct as you don't know how many variables you want to output upfront. So change the `eval` line to this:

```
% Create the vector with the correct name and data
eval(['B.' varname '= A;']);
```

Now you should have a struct called `B` that persists in the workspace after running the function with field names equal to your dynamically created variable names. Say for example one `varname` is `X`, you can now access it in your workspace as `B.X`.

But you should think very carefully about this code design, dynamically creating variables names is very unlikely to be the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `evalin`:

```
evalin('base', [varname '= B;']);
```

(which will not work quite right as-is; but please read on)

However, I strongly advise against using it.

It is often a lot less error-prone, usually considered good practice and in fact very common to have *predictable* outcomes of functions.

From all sorts of perspectives it is very undesirable to have a function that manipulates data beyond its own scope (i.e., in another workspace than its own), let alone assign unpredictable data to unpredictable variable names. This is unnecessarily hard to debug, maintain, and is not very portible. Also, using this function inside other functions does not what someone who doesn't know your function would think it does.

Why not use smoething like a structure:

```
function B = read_excel(filename)

    ...

    B.data = xlsread(filename,'B2:CT2');
    B.name = genvarname(name_str);
end
```

Then you always have the same name as output (`B`) which contains the same data (`B.data`) and whose `name` you can also use to reference other things dynamically (i.e., `A.(B.name)`).

Comment: Thank you, I'll take your warning and not use evalin, but I don't understand something about you example if I load into B 3 vectors i.e. 3 B.data and 3 B.name how would I go about for example plotting the data if I know the name? Is it, assuming I know one of the name is "foo" plot(B.foo)?

Comment: @GeorgeBora: I mean, the field `B.name` *contains* a string that is the name: `B.name=='foo';`. Example: `plot(B.data); title(B.name);`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `evalin` is the function `assignin`. It is less powerfull than `evalin`, but does exacty what you want - assign a variable in a workspace.

Usage:

```
assignin('base', 'var', val)
```